# checking a line of code in a file on quickbasic

Tags: passwords, qbasic, quickbasic

I'm trying to make my program have a dialogue box with a password that has been set in a file. I need help having it scan a line of code in a file and if the password entry is true, then proceed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show what code you have so far. Also, QuickBASIC doesn't have facilities to display a dialog (unless you draw it yourself in a graphics screen mode like SCREEN 12) Please confirm what language you're writing in. Could it be Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gets a password and compares it to a password in a file:

```
INPUT "Password", x$
OPEN "password.dat" FOR INPUT AS #1
INPUT #1, y$
IF x$ = y$ THEN PRINT "Match": ' do stuff
```